# Almost stationary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Prove that, if $\left \{ x_{n} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is almost stationary sequence, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=x$ .

Solution:

Sequence $\left \{ x_{n} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is almost stationary if: ($\exists s \in \mathbb{N}$)($\exists x \in \mathbb{X}$) ($\forall n \geq s$) $ x_{n}=x$.

So the definition of stationary sequence tells us, that all elements of the sequence with index $\geq s$ are equal to x.

So it proves directly that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=x$ .

Is that correct?

Comment: The statement "it proves directly" requires clarification

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I thought that it follows from the definition

Comment: The entire statement "if $\{x_n\}$ is almost stationary, then $x_n$ has a limit" follows completely from the definitions of "almost stationary" and of a limit.  If we are allowed to simply say that things are true "from the definition", then the solution to the entire problem would be to simply say "it's true from the definition".  However, since this question is meant to exercise your understanding of these definitions, saying "from the definition" does not suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more exact, let $ \epsilon >0$. Then we have

$$|x_n-x|=0< \epsilon$$

for all $n \ge s.$

Comment: and that would be enough for prove?

Comment: Yes, that is enough.